# Where does FusedLocationProviderClient fit in MVVM on Android?

Tags: android, android-mvvm, fusedlocationproviderclient

I am working on an Android application where I have to display weather data to users when they start the app. I'm following MVVM architecture and have successfully followed MVVM in all the use cases I have implemented including displaying data to users and manipulating SharedPreferences for Settings screen. I am using `FusedLocationProviderClient` for getting user's location, but it needs `Context` for instantiation. What should be the ideal way of dealing with this problem using while abiding by the MVVM architecture?

I cannot instantiate it from `ViewModel` since it will result in `Context` being passed to `ViewModel` hence causing potential memory leaks.

Currently, I am using `FusedLocationProviderClient` from my `Fragment` and updating data from there, but this is a very naive approach and clearly violates MVVM.

Comment: Instantiate it in your Activity, then pass it to the ViewModel (like you should be doing with all dependencies). Look into ViewModelFactory https://proandroiddev.com/view-model-creation-in-android-android-architecture-components-kotlin-ce9f6b93a46b

Comment: *I cannot instantiate it from ViewModel* technically you can if you use AndroidViewModel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get **Context** by extending your ViewModel from **AndroidViewModel** and then you can do SharedPreferences related stuff there without violating MVVM pattern.

Comment: *ViewModel should not contains android framework specific codes* why not? ViewModel itself is "android framework specific"

Comment: yeah right it belongs to jetpack by default so I'll change my answer accordingly

Comment: I'm a little bit confused about how to fit in in MVVM. I would like to receive live updates about latitude and longitude and I think I can do it in `ViewModel`  using ` `FusedLocationProviderClient` but I don't know in what method of the lifecycle it could be. Could you please help me @ZaferCelaloglu ? I'm learning Android and this is my first project.